# mcrypt_module_open() is deprecated error on laravel 5.4 + consolibyte quickbooks

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Good Day,

I tried integrating Quickbooks into laravel 5.4, I saw this tutorial in the net "http://lamparchitect.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-implement-quickbooks-online-api.html" I have successfully installed it on my localhost, also added the plugin successfull.

Now When I tried to use the connect button which accesses to oauth url.. I get to be redirected to QB page where it asks you to authorize the app or not.. when I clicked authorized button.. I got error from my laravel app

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Function mcrypt_module_open() is deprecated
in Aes.php (line 34)
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Function mcrypt_module_open() is deprecated', 'D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\quickbooks_appx\\vendor\\consolibyte\\quickbooks\\QuickBooks\\Encryption\\Aes.php', 34, array('key' => 'bcde1234', 'plain' => 'a:2:{i:0;s:48:"qyprdJZmHoC2RX8aG8EaUGKyJ6awxzVpDO7Nr2IKsqmUcZ0o";i:1;s:32:"b4e2SK3n6GduTsMl9pDhX0w1IWJHki5P";}', 'salt' => 'b4e2SK3n6GduTsMl9pDhX0w1IWJHki5P'))
in Aes.php (line 34)
at QuickBooks_Encryption_AES::encrypt('bcde1234', 'a:2:{i:0;s:48:"qyprdJZmHoC2RX8aG8EaUGKyJ6awxzVpDO7Nr2IKsqmUcZ0o";i:1;s:32:"b4e2SK3n6GduTsMl9pDhX0w1IWJHki5P";}')
in Driver.php (line 1401)
at QuickBooks_Driver->oauthAccessWrite('bcde1234', 'qyprd24BSQ8j0dG36yW7bNCzUrlwFPLpFdn2OFzItLALcFRL', 'qyprdJZmHoC2RX8aG8EaUGKyJ6awxzVpDO7Nr2IKsqmUcZ0o', 'QV7iDw7oaXpFWtxGLMe3kX7Ab1irgYxGaWX52nud', '193514559060839', 'QBO')
in IntuitAnywhere.php (line 417)
at QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere->handle('DO_NOT_CHANGE_ME', '12345')
in QuickBookController.php (line 53)
```

Comment: There a problem in this lib ==> [Is this lib dead?](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/issues/174) and also [here](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/issues/158) !

Comment: I see thanks for the link Sir.. been searching all day to solve this.. could you recommend a work around?

Comment: Take a look at this [laravel-quickbooks](https://github.com/myleshyson/laravel-quickbooks) !

Comment: Thanks for the tip Sir..

Comment: If you want i can add an answer that you can accept to help other poeple :)

Comment: @Maraboc Do add an answer but it needs to be more than just a link. It also shgould not be a work-around to use mcrypt, mcrypt wqs removed "for cause".

Comment: since I had the option to do so.. I did just switched my php version to 5.6 and I made it running...